# To create a dynamic interactive range of cells that give the desired output of number of hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a raw data table consisting of columns as time periods and row labels as the names of technicians. The data filled is the registration number of the car.

I had to calculate two things:

1. The number of hours each person has spent working in a day
2. The number of hours spent on one car by individual technicians involved.

I was able to achieve the first task by using pivot tables but am stuck at the second one.
Kindly suggest some easy method. 
Thanks

Attached is a reference image dummy data.

[image: table of service vehicles tracked]

Comment: If you use pivot tables, then use `registration number of the car` as row identifier in the pivot table

Comment: That's the issue, there is no separate column that lists the registration numbers of the cars. these numbers are inserted in the table as per when the car was being serviced and by whom.
such a field is not gonna show up in the pivot table.

Comment: To understand you correctly because (2) is not clear: You want for every car, a list with names and how long they used that specific car in total (independently from the date)?

Comment: i want a table, with the registration numbers of the cars in one column, and the number of hours spent by each person on it in the subsequent columns. this has to come from the same raw data. From this table i would further create a pivot table to create a graph with slicers etc. 
including date would complicate things too much.

Comment: the way i thought about it is, a table showing the duplicate values occurring on the table, shown as a list. this will be the column of registration numbers. and further, it will show the count of that duplicate value in the appropriate column of the service person's name.so this way i get the nu,ber of hours spent by each technician on that car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code which makes a new data table from your existing table and gives you data in a format from which making Pivot table is feasible,

```
Sub K()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, LR1 As Long
Dim reg As String, person As String
Dim DT As Date

Range("AB:AD").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 5 To LR
For i = 4 To 25

If Cells(j, i).Value = "" Then


Else
reg = Cells(j, i).Value
LR1 = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DT = Cells(j, 1).Value
person = Cells(j, 2).Value

Range("AC" & LR1).Offset(1, 0).Value = reg
Range("AC" & LR1).Offset(1, 1).Value = person
Range("AC" & LR1).Offset(1, -1).Value = DT

End If

Next
Next

Range("AB1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
    Range("AC1").FormulaR1C1 = "Reg. No."
    Range("AD1").FormulaR1C1 = "Person"
    Range("AE1").FormulaR1C1 = "Count"

    LR1 = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("AE2:AE" & LR1).Value = 0.5






End Sub
```

This table can be used as a source for PIVOT and every time you run the code it will give a complete data set based on data given.

Comment: This worked quite effectively!
Thank you so much!

Also is there a way to refresh the source data for the pivot table that I will create using this new table, every time I run the code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve this using pivot table as the data you wish to be present in your new table namely the car's registration number, pivot won't let you put these registration number as row/column entries.

You should take help of VBA.
you can use loop to read this data and create a count for every car, you should use `if else` loop. to set condition on which entry should it count and which it shouldn't.

Comment: Loop from your first column and create a new table from which you can create a pivot table, since you want to use slicers and dynamic range. Once you get that range in desired output use pivot.

Comment: You range should be like this.
Date Reg. name